# Rank data with subsets

Tags: r

Say I have data in the following form:

```
> x <- data.frame(yr = c(1,1,1,1), wk = c(1,1,2,2), id = c("a","b","a","b"), dat1 = c(3,1,10,11), dat2 = c(3,1,10,11), dat3 = c(4,2,12,8))
> x
yr  wk   id   dat1  dat2  dat3
01  01    a     3     3     4
01  01    b     1     1     2
01  02    a     10    10    12
01  02    b     11    11    8
```

I want to return a data frame of `rank` over the subsets `yr` and `wk`.  Is there a shorthand way to do this?

```
yr   wk   id  dat1Rnk  dat2Rnk  dat3Rnk
01   01   a     1         1        1
01   01   b     2         2        2
01   02   a     2         2        1
01   02   b     1         1        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something as the following using `data.table`. First define the columns, then negate the columns (because you rank in decreasing order), then reassign the columns

```
library(data.table)
cols <- paste0("dat", 1:3)
setDT(x)[, (cols) := lapply(-.SD, frank), .SDcols = cols, by = .(yr, wk)]
x
#    yr wk id dat1 dat2 dat3
# 1:  1  1  a    1    1    1
# 2:  1  1  b    2    2    2
# 3:  1  2  a    2    2    1
# 4:  1  2  b    1    1    2
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(yr, wk) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(rank(-.)), -id)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# Groups: yr, wk [2]
# 
#      yr    wk     id  dat1  dat2  dat3
#   (dbl) (dbl) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1     1     1      a     1     1     1
# 2     1     1      b     2     2     2
# 3     1     2      a     2     2     1
# 4     1     2      b     1     1     2
```

Comment: Base version - `x[cols] <- lapply(x[cols], function(d) ave(-d, x[c("yr","wk")], FUN=rank) )`

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Sadly, I realized I need to loop because some of the rank orders (asc/desc) change from year to year in the real data.  I may do some kind of mass-sign-inversion so I can just use this.  This is a big help, thanks!

Comment: @thelatemail that's an a nice alternative. I was thinking how to make it simple in base.